# How to make a correct local JSON file and correct model using swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, parsing

I have an app, where I should parse all the data from local JSON file to my label, songs. There is a JSON file, with one array, with two arrays. For example, I need to use "loop data" in one of the view controller, and "beatloopsdata" in another. When I run this, I've got an error, that data corrupted. There is my JSON File:

```
{
"beatpackdata": [
    {
        "loopsdictionary": [
            {
                "nameOfLoop": "Away we go",
                "nameOfProducer": "Tubular Kingz",
                "countOfLoops": "28",
                "genreOfLoops": "Lo-fi Hip Hop"
            },
            {
                "nameOfLoop": "Test",
                "nameOfProducer": "Testing",
                "countOfLoops": "25",
                "genreOfLoops": "Lo-fi"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "beatloopsdictionary": [
            {
                "loopName" : "Alien",
                "instrument" :"Arp",
                "songName" : "alienarpjason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Big Brake",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "BigBrake_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Bongo Beats",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "BongoBeats_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Dreaming",
                "instrument" :"Keys",
                "songName" : "Dreaming_Keys_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Funky Groove",
                "instrument" :"Bass",
                "songName" : "FunkyGroove_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Futurist",
                "instrument" :"Arp",
                "songName" : "Futurist_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Hoping for change",
                "instrument" :"Arp",
                "songName" : "HopingForChange_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Manic",
                "instrument" :"Bass",
                "songName" : "Manic_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Sassy",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "Sassy_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Serious",
                "instrument" :"Arp",
                "songName" : "Serious_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Stable Bricks",
                "instrument" :"Bass",
                "songName" : "StableBrick_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Thump",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "Thump_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Tropic",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "TropicVibe_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I've created a model, but not sure that all is correct. I've tried my best, but it's third time when I use a local JSON file:

```
import Foundation

struct BeatData: Codable {
    let beatpackdata: [BeatPackData]
}

struct BeatPackData: Codable {
    let loopdata: [BeatLoopsData]
    let beatloopsdata: [LoopData]
}

struct LoopData: Codable {
    let loop_name: String
    let Instrument: String
    let song_name: String
    let producer: String
}

struct BeatLoopsData: Codable {
    let nameOfLoop: String
    let nameOfProducer: String
    let countOfLoops: String
    let genreOfLoops: String
}
```

Parse Function:

```
private func parseJSON() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beatpackdata", ofType: "json") else {
            return
        }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            beatPackData = try JSONDecoder().decode(BeatData.self, from: jsonData)
            
            if let beatPackData = beatPackData {
                print(beatPackData)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: The value for `loopdata` is clearly a dictionary so `[]` is wrong. Replace it with `{}`. And I would remove all that redundant `...data` occurrences and replace the snake_case keys with lowerCamelCase ones.

Comment: As I understand, need to move at the JSON file, but how I should rename it in my model?

Comment: `let loopdata: BeatLoopsData`. Your naming is really confusing.

Comment: Done, I've renamed all in my model, but how to fix a JSON file?

Comment: As I said, in the value of key `loopdata` replace the square brackets with braces

Comment: I've make this changes, but still not working. Check I've update post with my parse function

Comment: The edit is a completely different JSON which doesn't match the model anymore. Start with a small chunk of the JSON and read carefully the error messages. By the way, there is also `url(forResource: withExtension:)` in `Bundle`

Comment: Could you try to make changes, because I really don't know how to make it

Comment: as always, just copy your json data into "https://app.quicktype.io/" and get the correct data structures, and use that in you code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the json data into quicktype, and used the generated data structures in the code.
So here is the working code. You can tell your teacher, you did the school assignment all on your own.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let beatpackdata: [Beatpackdatum]
}

struct Beatpackdatum: Codable {
    let loopsdictionary: [Loopsdictionary]?
    let beatloopsdictionary: [Beatloopsdictionary]?
}

struct Beatloopsdictionary: Codable {
    let loopName, instrument, songName: String
    let producer: String
}

struct Loopsdictionary: Codable {
    let nameOfLoop, nameOfProducer, countOfLoops, genreOfLoops: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing testing")
            .onAppear {
                parseJSON()
            }
    }
    
    func parseJSON() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beatpackdata", ofType: "json") else {
            print("\n-------> bundle path error")
            return
        }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
            print("\n-------> response: \(response)")
        }
        catch {
            print("\n====> error: \(error)" )
        }
        return
    }

}
```

EDIT 1: here is the data I used, I put this data into a file called "beatpackdata.json" in my xcode project.

```
{
"beatpackdata": [
    {
        "loopsdictionary": [
            {
                "nameOfLoop": "Away we go",
                "nameOfProducer": "Tubular Kingz",
                "countOfLoops": "28",
                "genreOfLoops": "Lo-fi Hip Hop"
            },
            {
                "nameOfLoop": "Test",
                "nameOfProducer": "Testing",
                "countOfLoops": "25",
                "genreOfLoops": "Lo-fi"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "beatloopsdictionary": [
            {
                "loopName" : "Alien",
                "instrument" :"Arp",
                "songName" : "alienarpjason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Big Brake",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "BigBrake_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Bongo Beats",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "BongoBeats_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Dreaming",
                "instrument" :"Keys",
                "songName" : "Dreaming_Keys_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Funky Groove",
                "instrument" :"Bass",
                "songName" : "FunkyGroove_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Futurist",
                "instrument" :"Arp",
                "songName" : "Futurist_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Hoping for change",
                "instrument" :"Arp",
                "songName" : "HopingForChange_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Manic",
                "instrument" :"Bass",
                "songName" : "Manic_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Sassy",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "Sassy_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Serious",
                "instrument" :"Arp",
                "songName" : "Serious_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Stable Bricks",
                "instrument" :"Bass",
                "songName" : "StableBrick_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Thump",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "Thump_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "loopName" : "Tropic",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "TropicVibe_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: can you explain what part is not working, and I'll try to look into it. What system are you using?

Comment: Could you check my json file, maybe there is some problem? Because I've put all your code, but still not get data from json. Because I need to put data to my labels in project.

Comment: updated my answer with the data I used. Works very well for me.

Comment: I've created a model file with your code and data loader with fun parseJson. Now I input this in view controller: let data = DataLoader().beatData and then trying to do this: cell.loopNameLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].beatpackdata.beatloopsdictionary[indexPath.row].loopName

Comment: so does my answer work? do you get the printed response? If not tell me what is not working.

Comment: I've put print(data) and get this: []
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]

Comment: what's print(data)? I have print("\n-------> response: \(response)") does that work?

Comment: It's didn't show nothing, I've put you model and func in view controller now, and nothing

Comment: so you are getting errors in code that you are not showing us. Is that correct? Or are you getting errors in my code?

Comment: In your code, because I've put it. Maybe I can screen share with you

Comment: are you getting errors when you use my answer? If so tell me where in my code.

Comment: I don't get errors. I don't get printed the data :)

Comment: Ok. Did you create a file named "beatpackdata.json" and put that file in your xcode project, as I explained? What system are you using?

Comment: Sure, I have this file in Xcode project. What you mean system?

Comment: what macos are you using, what targets are you setting, ios 14, ios15, macos 12, macCatalyst, what exactly are you trying to produce?

Comment: I've build new project and got now this ====> error: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.})))

Comment: well that's probably because you did not copy and pasted the json data correctly in the file. Try again from my answer data.

Comment: Now I get data, but have problem to pass it too my labels, got an error "index out of range".....

Comment: that's for another question. If my answer is correct for your initial question, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Now Your Josn Is look like

```
{
  "beatpackdata": {
    "loopsdictionary": [
      {
        "nameOfLoop": "Away we go",
        "nameOfProducer": "Tubular Kingz",
        "countOfLoops": "28",
        "genreOfLoops": "Lo-fi Hip Hop"
      },
      {
        "nameOfLoop": "Test",
        "nameOfProducer": "Testing",
        "countOfLoops": "25",
        "genreOfLoops": "Lo-fi"
      }
    ],
    "beatloopsdictionary": [
      {
        "loopName": "Alien",
        "instrument": "Arp",
        "songName": "alienarpjason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Big Brake",
        "instrument": "Drums",
        "songName": "BigBrake_Drums_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Bongo Beats",
        "instrument": "Drums",
        "songName": "BongoBeats_Drums_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Dreaming",
        "instrument": "Keys",
        "songName": "Dreaming_Keys_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Funky Groove",
        "instrument": "Bass",
        "songName": "FunkyGroove_Bass_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Futurist",
        "instrument": "Arp",
        "songName": "Futurist_Arp_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Hoping for change",
        "instrument": "Arp",
        "songName": "HopingForChange_Arp_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Manic",
        "instrument": "Bass",
        "songName": "Manic_Bass_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Sassy",
        "instrument": "Drums",
        "songName": "Sassy_Drums_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Serious",
        "instrument": "Arp",
        "songName": "Serious_Arp_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Stable Bricks",
        "instrument": "Bass",
        "songName": "StableBrick_Bass_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Thump",
        "instrument": "Drums",
        "songName": "Thump_Drums_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      },
      {
        "loopName": "Tropic",
        "instrument": "Drums",
        "songName": "TropicVibe_Drums_Jason.mp3",
        "producer": "Stefan Guy"
      }
    ],
    }
  }
```

Model File

```
struct BeatData: Codable {
    let loopsdictionary: [LoopData]
    let beatloopsdictionary: [BeatLoopsData]
    
    static func objBeatData(fromDict : NSDictionary) -> BeatData?{
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let data = fromDict.toData(jsonPath: "beatpackdata")
             return try decoder.decode(BeatData.self, from:data)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct LoopData: Codable {
    let nameOfLoop: String
    let nameOfProducer: String
    let countOfLoops: String
    let genreOfLoops: String
}

struct BeatLoopsData: Codable {
    let loopName: String
    let instrument: String
    let songName: String
    let producer: String
}

public extension NSDictionary {
   
    func toData(jsonPath : String = "data") -> Data{
        let dataDict = self.value(forKeyPath: jsonPath)
        do{
        let dataJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataDict, options: .prettyPrinted)
        return dataJson
        }catch let error{
           print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
       return Data()
    }
}
```

How To Use

```
func beatpackdataJsonFile() -> NSDictionary?{
    var tempDict : NSDictionary?
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beatpackdata", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: path!)
    do{
        tempDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
        
    }catch let error{
        print("Json Serialization : \(error.localizedDescription)")
         }
    return tempDict
}

//Parse Data
if let dictSuccess = beatpackdataJsonFile() {
    let data = BeatData.objBeatData(fromDict: dictSuccess)
}
```

Comment: Where you get this? "toData" Because I've got an error: Value of type 'NSDictionary' has no member 'toData'

Comment: Hey, I had edit the answer now you can use it and update the issue of  NSDictionary has no member "toData".

Comment: Looks good, will try it! Maybe you know how to pass this data correct to the label?

Comment: You have to create an instance of Model like let objData: BeatData? and then use when where you want like objData. loopsdictionary[index]. nameOfLoop.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to solve the error - "Index out of range" ?

Comment: Got this error with your code: Thread 1: "*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write"

Comment: have you edit the JSON this error comes when JSON is not able to find the key And for index out of range i don't know-how you use the data in tableview cell

Comment: I've created instance like you told and now using like this - cell.loopNameLabel.text = dataNew.beatLoops[indexPath.row].name

Comment: you have two array loopsdictionary, beatloopsdictionary but in table view to show data you need one array of the same model class that way it crashes. Could show me the design or logic that you want to implement.

Comment: Maybe we can contact, I will screen share with you